# If $x$ is a limit point of subset $A$ of $X$, is it necessarily true that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$, $(Y, \upsilon)$ be topological spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous application. If $x$ is a limit point of subset $A$ of $X$, is it
necessarily true that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

Let $x \in A'$ and suppose that there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $V \cap f(A) \subset \{f(x)\}$. As $x \in \overline{A}$, then since $f$ is continuous it follows that $ f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$, which implies that $f(x) \in \overline {f(A)} $ and so $ V \cap f(A) = \{f (x)\} $, that is, $ f(x) $ is an isolated point of $ f(A ) $. On the other hand, since $ x \in V $ y $ f $ is continuous, there is an open neighborhood $ U $ of $ x $ in $ A $ such that $ f(U) \subset V $. Therefore $ f (U \cap A) \subset \{f (x)\}$. Clearly $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$

This is a part of my reasoning, could you tell me if I'm doing well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily true. Take, for example, function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = 0$. $0$ is obviously a limit point of $\mathbb R$, but $f(0) = 0$ isn't a limit point of $f(\mathbb R) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Why the continuity of $f$ in the hypothesis?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the "why". Are you asking why the question was formulated this way? It depends on source of question, but probably because for arbitrary $f$ it's obviously false - just take $f(x) = p$ and $f(X \setminus \{x\}) = q \neq p$.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are trying to prove that for every subset $A$ of $X$ , one has $f(cl(A))\subset cl(f(A))$ under the continuous map from $X$ to $Y$.

Let $f$ is continuous. Let $A$ be a subset of $X$.We need to prove if $x\in cl(A)$ then $f(x)\in cl(f(A))$.